# Facing Nvlddmkm.Sys Error on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

Recently I started facing this error on my PC, I don't know what is the reason behind it.I ran a disk check to find out what happened but nothing helped. Could anyone please help me out on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This apparently happens when you are having driver issues with an Nvidia  graphics card. You may want to update Windows and your card drivers and see if that helps solve the issue. Otherwise, you can try generally re-installing the drivers you have. One other option is try using the drivers in compatibility mode as detailed in this link -- https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings-winpc/blue-screen-error-nvlddmkmsys-windows10/ac4350b0-861e-4cb1-ad6d-ebbd9d42a9a8

Answer (score 1):

"nvlddmkm.sys” is related to NVIDIA driver. 
I don't know if you have performed and actions on your computer such as update, upgrade or others which update will replace your video driver with a new one, upgrade might cause not compatibility issue. 
Go to Nvidia website and download the latest audio driver for your computer. If issue occur, delete the driver and reboot computer to install general driver.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is probably caused by driver incompatibility with Windows 10.
Users face this error after their system has been upgraded or sometimes after the drivers have been updated.

If you have just updated to windows 10 then download the latest driver from nvidia

If you already had windows 10 and this just started out of the blue try to roll back your drivers.